# Put forms of different size side-by-side with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is what I'm trying to do:

[image: trying to do]

Here is what I'm getting right now with the code below:

[image: what i'm getting]

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
  </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
  </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
  </div>
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the middle element, assuming its the highest one, to the right. By default, a col will be floated to the left, just override it. See the fiddle below, remove the float right and see what happens.

```css
.centered-form:nth-of-type(1){
  height:400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.centered-form:nth-of-type(2){
  height:800px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

.centered-form:nth-of-type(3){
  height:400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 centered-form">
</div>
```

Comment: still doing it... is something with my "row", it is not including the last element in the row...

Comment: The css works for the HTML you provided. If there is something you're not including then include it so we can make it work for your usecase.